# MvvmCross Xamarin.Forms (iOS): Using a TabbedPage within a MasterDetail page

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

How can I use a TabbedPage within a MasterDetail navigation correctly? Currently I use this two Attributes above my Tabbed-Root:

```
[MvxTabbedPagePresentation(TabbedPosition.Root)]
[MvxMasterDetailPagePresentation(Position = MasterDetailPosition.Detail, WrapInNavigationPage = true, NoHistory = true)]
```

But sometimes it does not work and show the Back Navigation instead of the Hamburger-Menu icon. If I swap the two than it works again but if I change something somewhere else within my app it might be occur again and I have to swap the two again... It's kinda strange and I don't get why this happens.

Answer (score 3):

Okay I found the answer. It's not possible to use double Attributes but there is a Property named `HostViewModelType` on the Attributes to handle this.